# runtime error at putting both layout with background image and imagebutton?

Tags: android, android-layout

I use android-8 (2.2), and when I try to set a background to linearlayout and put a imagebutton, it gives runtime error. Do anyone knows that how to fix it in this release of android?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:id="@+id/signUpLayout"
              android:background="@drawable/loginbackground">
    <ImageButton android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                         android:id="@+id/signUpButton"
                         android:src="@drawable/facebooksignupbutton"
                         android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                         android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                         android:clickable="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the logs:

```
03-29 03:06:46.820: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1012): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.CashFinance/com.CashFinance.SignUpPage}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageButton
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2362)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:168)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1329)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageButton
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:361)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1956)
        at com.CashFinance.SignUpPage.onCreate(SignUpPage.java:20)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
        ... 11 more
        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
        ... 26 more
        Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:832)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2988)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:131)
        at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:88)
        at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:84)
        ... 29 more
```

Comment: Actually It should be line #8 . I have removed some empty linearlayouts here for not to confuse your mind...

Comment: Probably you used later version than android-8. As I mentioned, I need to use android-8. I found that this was a issue on android-8 and fixed at android-9. Is there a way to implement it in android-8.

Comment: I have realized smt. in bottom. It says Out of memory.. What is the memory limit, which size I sould use then?

Comment: 169kb jpg background 11kb gif button. Both of them sized 1080x1966

Comment: When removing src line it works. And I have added very small image to button it worked. But what is the max size of imagebutton permitted, I think thats the issue..

Comment: Yeah, I have divided sizes by 2 and working now. But I have just wondered what is the limitation.. Thanks for help btw